# Can not debug a JDBC line of code in Netbeans

Tags: java, debugging, jdbc, netbeans

I'm trying to learn JDBC with a little java background here. I was following a tutorial and I started my study with these two classes. This is the first one (I don't know what task this class performs):

```
public class NewClass {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PersonelDB", "root", "root");

        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSONEL");

        while (rs.next()) {
            int x = rs.getInt("ID");
            String s = rs.getString("AD");
        }

    }
    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
  }
}
```

Following is the part that I am just working on (from the other class, a JFrame screen). I did not paste the whole code, as I thought it would not be necessary.

```
private void bttn_queryActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                           
    try {
        // Establish connection 
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/PersonelDB", "root", "root");

        // Get statement
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        // Execute query 
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSONEL");

        while (rs.next()) {
            int x = rs.getInt("ID");
            String s = rs.getString("AD");
        }
    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(NewClass.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

The problem is when I put a breakpoint on line `Connection con` etc and try to debug the file, I get the following error:

```
Not able to submit breakpoint MethodBreakpoint [liang260117.TestMethodOverloading].max '(II)I', reason: Breakpoint belongs to disabled source root 'C:\Users\Grundig1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Liang260117\src'. See Window/Debugging/Sources.
Not able to submit breakpoint MethodBreakpoint [pkg010217.CheckSudokuSolution].getSolution '()[[I', reason: Breakpoint belongs to disabled source root 'C:\Users\Grundig1\Documents\NetBeansProjects\Liang010217\src'. See Window/Debugging/Sources.
```

Can anyone help me to deal with this problem, please?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you missing the Class.forName call from the tutorial?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't understand you. Could you be more clear or type the necessary code exactly, please?

Comment: @ChantryCargill `Class.forName()` hasn't been necessary with JDBC for ten years.

Answer (score 0):

I watched the tutorial again and at this point, it seems that the professor himself encounters with these errors, too. So, no need to stick to this problem.

By the way, here is the link of the tutorial (in Turkish), if anyone is interested:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tNsmna9BBow&list=PLmrqppiiS_vNsFPtZyadMDgxjzvSvIPTX&index=8

Answer (score 0):

The first issue I see is that you are not cleaning up resources properly. Generally, when you define a connection or a statement or a result set, you do so with the following design pattern.

```
Resource resource = null;
Resource2 resource2 = null;
try {
  resource = getResource();
  resource2 = resource.getAnotherResource();
  // do stuff
}
catch(ResourceException ex) {
  // do stuff
}
finally {
  if(resource2 != null) {
    resource2.close();
  }
  if(resource != null) {
    resource.close();
  }
}
```

Notice that the resource is cleaned up in the finally block if you manage to define it. If the close methods throw exceptions, they would need to be caught individually. Java 7 has a condensed version of this using a *try with resources* as well.

You're also missing a Class.forName call for your derby driver (required for JDBC < 4). Is this in the tutorial somewhere? This loads in the driver that is used for connecting to the database.

I don't trust the quality of the video tutorial you are following, as the above resource handling is necessary for any meaningful project and it does not seem like the professor realizes it. There may be other issues with your setup that we cannot determine without more information. Although, I do not speak Turkish.

Also, where are your import statements?

Comment: So, what should I do, actually? write a try catch block for each line of code (i.e., connection, statement, resultset) or is there an alternative way that works for all of them? For the second part of your answer; still, I have no idea about that `Class.forName` stuff.

Comment: @TossTheAtoms I'll modify my answer with an example using 2 resources. Also, you may not require Class.forName. It's going to be impossible to determine the problem with your setup without us either going through the tutorial or miraculously having already witnessed the issue before.

Comment: To be honest, I really appreciate your interest but as you've said before, my tutorial is not competent much and many times I choose not to stick to unusual problems because they start to confuse me after some time. Anyway, thank you very much for your time and interest.